# How is a 64 bit decimal stored in 32 bit addresses?

Tags: binary, mips, cpu-architecture

I am doing some programming on MIPS which has a bunch of 32 bit registers but I also know that you can store 64 bit integers, how does this work? Does the integer take up two registers? If so how does the system know to combine the two registers into one long string of binary

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#Integer), the 32-bit MIPS instruction set includes "Load Double Word" and "Store Double Word" instructions that load/store a pair of consecutive registers from/to memory.

For the actual arithmetic, it looks like you typically have to use multiple instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the documentation for your platform, since it may vary. For example, for MIPS 32-bits, check something like this [quick reference](http://www.mips.com/media/files/MD00565-2B-MIPS32-QRC-01.01.pdf) (see the "C calling convention" part).

For more details, though, you'd need a more complete reference (the quick one doesn't list any 64-bit arithmetic instructions that I could see, so if they don't exist, you'd have to implement them yourself, and then you can use your own convention for how to store the values).